# Can I put gypsum and paint finish on top of a concrete fast set repair mortar?

Tags: repair, concrete, painting, finishing

I have a finished concrete pillar in my living room that I need to be patched and painted.
The pillar has final gypsum and paint on top of concrete. Since the concrete is chipped off I need to use a fast set repair mortar (such as QUIKRETE® FastSet™ Repair Mortar) to repair the concrete.

But I don't know if the gypsum material can be added on top of the repair mortar or not? is there a specific product that I can add on top to prepare the surface for paint?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a setting joint compound (maybe durabond) rather than mud because it's more durable and moisture resistant.  It's more time-consuming to sand, however.  Either should stick to concrete and both should get a coat of primer before painting.  If have old or really glossy concrete, you can prep the surface with a little Muriatic acid to etch the surface and get a better bond, but that shouldn't be necessary for fresh-cured mortar.

Comment: Durabond gets very hard and is no fun at all to sand, so apply it sparingly and cleanly as possible. It's tough stuff, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would not hesitate to skim over clean dry concrete with drywall mud. As long as the concrete NEVER has a chance to get wet.